# How can I get my internet connection from a specific network adapter?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet-connection, lan

In my enterprise network we have two ways to surf the web, by Wi-Fi network or by LAN network.

The Wi-Fi network does not have restrictions but the LAN is restricted by firewall. I like to be connected in both at the same time because all the servers and resources are available in the LAN. But, When I am connected with both connections enable, the internet goes by LAN, with the restrictions described before.

How can I configure my browser's Internet connection to go by Wi-Fi instead of LAN when I have enable both connections? I've been thinking about the possibility of installing a proxy in my laptop and pointing it to the Wi-Fi and then configuring my browser to use that proxy. Is that a good option?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the Default Gateway on the LAN adapter (unless it's assigned via DHCP) and then the only gateway will be via the wireless connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'route' command to remove the default route for the LAN interface.  This will leave the the WiFi adapter with the connection for the Internet.  Not sure if you are on linux or windows, the command will differ between the two.